# C# send data over serial port in binary mode

Tags: c#, oop, binary, serial-port

TeraTerm can transmit files using "Binary mode". Can someone please let me know what is the difference between "Binary mode" and "Not-binary mode"?

I have to do the same on a C# project and I'm not really sure if I need something special to send a file in "Binary mode", its a case of lack of knowledge.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please let me know what is the difference between "Binary mode" and "Not-binary mode"?

"Binary mode" traditionally will transfer the file without any processing nor use any protocol.  The data from the file will be transferred byte for byte: nothing will be inserted or removed or translated.

For TeraTerm, binary sending is described in its [documentation](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/) as

```
If you select this option, received characters are sent without any modifications.
Otherwise, new-line codes are converted and control characters (except TAB, LF and
CR) are stripped out.
```

For TeraTerm the opposite of this "binary mode" could be called (ASCII) text mode.

---

The alternative to binary/text modes for file transmission by a terminal emulator program would employ a file transfer protocol such as kermit, xmodem, ymodem, or zmodem.

Comment: Ahhh, nice. Thank you very much. Now it is much moe clear to me. That means, as far as I understand, I just have to send the bytes of my file over the serial port. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what TeraTerm is but my guess is that binary-mode is there to send binary files over the serial port. Also it could be that the input-dialog is now in bin not hex format. Like writing "0x00" is now "00000000".

Comment: Thank you. The question is: What is the difference of sending binary files over serial port and sending a, i.e. text file, over serial port. I was not able to figure out.